# Unable to start the windows service which connects to the remote SQL server

Tags: c#, windows-services

Hi I have created a windows service which connects with remote sql server database(VPN required), fetches the table records and store it into a excel file which is placed at specific location(c:\TestService).

I have installed the service using installutil -i "MassUpdateChargecode_SQL.exe" command,service has been installed but unable to start the service getting following error.

[Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Upc35.png)

Comment: Did you check eventviewer, maybe there is a detailed error?

Comment: @fluidguid I didnt get any details in event viewer

Comment: Write this code in your start function. It will invoke visual studio debugger, and you'll be able to find out what the error is.  Debugger.Launch();